# Refresh UIImageView in Swift after Image File Has Changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

In my app I am setting the image of a `UIImageView` as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // ...
    self.currentPlayer.image = UIImage(named: appDelegate.appSupportDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(currentPlayer!.id!.UUIDString + ".jpg"))
}
```

In a different view, I allow the user to change the image, namely replace the file with a new one while keeping the name. When I return to this view the old picture is still shown. The app seems to remember the outdated picture even when I load a different player profile in between. How can I force the `UIImageView` to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. Change the code to:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // ...
    self.currentPlayer.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: appDelegate.appSupportDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(currentPlayer!.id!.UUIDString + ".jpg"))
}
```